# How can I show only the row of a table that has the same value that was entered in a textbox with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table of rank where I type the ID of the rank and it shows me only the column line that has this line as my code:

```
$('button').click(function () {

var data = $("textarea").val(); 
var rank = $("#rank").val(); 
if(rank == ""){
    alert("digit rank number");
}
else{
data = data.replace(/\s/, " #"); 
data = data.replace(/([0-9]\s)/g, "$1#"); 
var lines = data.split("#"), 
    output = [],
    i;
for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i++)
    output.push("<tr><td>" + lines[i].slice(0,-1).split(",").join("</td><td>") + "</td></tr>");

output = "<table>" + output.join("") + "</table>";

var valuefinal = $(output).find('tr').filter(function(){ 
    return $(this).children('td').eq(1).text() == rank;
});

 $('#fileDisplayArea').html(valuefinal);
}
});
```

I'm doing this filter in that part of the code

```
var valuefinal = $(output).find('tr').filter(function(){ 
        return $(this).children('td').eq(1).text() == rank;
    });

     $('#fileDisplayArea').html(valuefinal);
```

[DEMO CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/JoaoFelipePego/qM6Fj/2/)

(Forgive me if you did not understand something, my english sucks. I hope it is clear what I need.)

Comment: `.eq()` is 0-based, so you get the first row cell with `.eq(0)`. I assume that your code will work then.

Comment: @the_tiger Yes! Work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change this -

```
return $(this).children('td').eq(1).text() == rank;
```

to this -

```
return $(this).children('td').eq(0).text() == rank;
```

`.eq()` is a zero-based array method.

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/qM6Fj/19/

http://api.jquery.com/eq/

Answer (score -1):

You need to have a search feature for the contents you have displayed in the table is what i got.....
You can use jQuery DataTable for this purpose which does this job [link](http://www.datatables.net/) .. scroll down to see the table show with sort, search etc features